# SyncAdapter to receive chat messages?

Tags: android, websocket, android-workmanager, android-syncadapter, android-intentservice

For my chat app I am looking for a good way to sync messages while the app is in background.

At the moment I have a websocket. When the app comes to foreground, messages get synced. This makes the app looking laggy. Like WhatsApp I need a way to have all messaged synchronized before the app gets in foreground.

I thought about the following solution:
I set up a SyncAdapter which gets triggerd by a push notification ("new message for chat xy"). Then inside the SyncAdapter I fetch new messages.

Now the problem is I do not want to connect (e.g. via REST) for each line which has been written. And also I don't want to wait x minutes to bundle new messages.

As I said before, I already have a websocket which gets established when the app goes to foreground. Is it a good idea to move this code to the SyncAadapter? Can I keep the connection open there or should I close it if I dont receive a message for x minutes? The only problem I see is, if an user is not able to receive push messages.

If anyone knows of famous chat apps do it, please point me to this direction.

Answer (score 1):

[Signal (secure messaging app)](https://www.signal.org/) is [opensource](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android). You can take a look at how they implemented a real-world solution with the goal of implementing a very secure chat.

Depending of what is your main goal you can choose a simpler implementation with available pieces. However I think that you still need a few pieces:

1. A push system to wake up your application when a new message is available
2. A way to retrieve the message when the app is in background
3. A system that monitor network and retries sending a message as soon network is back

The first item can be solved with [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) the second and third can be implemented with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

I would avoid to keep something on the device with an open connection to check for new messages for two main reasons:

- battery consumption
- background restrictions

Comment: Thanks, but imagine multiple users are chatting, new lines every few seconds. How to implement 2.? A rest call for each message would take too much battery I think.

Comment: My point 2 covers when the app is in the background. I'm also not sure that having the connection always active vs doing a REST call for each message is much different from a battery point of view. I would do some tests and use the battery historian to check.

But you can also have a different way to keep the connection/communication active while the user has the app in foreground.

Comment: You mean it is possible to create a shared connection which can be used by: the frontend thread and the background thread (workmanager)?

Comment: You can pass the connection to the Worker using a custom WorkerFactory: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-workmanager-with-dagger-1029688c0978

Also Hilt has some support for this: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack